# How to make a table with inner lines in r markdown when kniting to PDF?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I made a table in rmd with the following code:

```
|Option|Description|
|----|----|
|Text1|Description1|
|Text2|Description2|
|Text3|Description3|
```

When kniting to PDF, the table was rendered as a three-line table.

[image]

I don't like three-line tables very much, because when the tables are long and wide, sometimes it's hard to quickly figure out which row the cells on the right of the table correspond to.

So, I wonder if there is a way for the tables in the pdf generated from rmd to be rendered as non-three-line tables, just like typora do.
[image]

I googled the problem but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Try `flextable` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st option**

Try `flextable` library. For instance:

````
```{r} 
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)
data.frame(Option = c("Option1", "Option2", "Option3"), Description = c("Text1", "Text2", "Text3")) %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  theme_box() # or  theme_vanilla()
```
````

And lateron adjust the required [themes](https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/format.html#theme-functions) and/or formating.

**2nd option**

Try `kable` as well:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
data.frame(Option = c("Option1", "Option2", "Option3"), Description = c("Text1", "Text2", "Text3")) %>% 
  
kable() %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = TRUE) %>%
  row_spec(2, background = "lightgray")
```

Comment: Wow! I've been trying to get this by modifying the markdon syntax. I never thought it could be done by R. Although this approach requires converting the markdown table into a dataframe first, I think it's not a hassle, a little regex will do the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Cloud Cool! Actually there are other packages that can be used for the same purpose. Their functionality vary. For instance it seems `flextable` is easier to use for `docx` markdown. So there is a list of other libraries worth be read about.

Comment: I have tried both flextable and kable, and found that flextable also works better for pdf. When I use kable, the tables in the output pdf are not arranged in order.